# Microsoft Classic QDK simulator

Tags: programming, simulation, q#

Is it possible to change the simulator used by the Classic QDK with Python simulation ?
It's reported that Classic QDK supports several simulators (sparse, full-state...). Which one is used when called from Python environment, and is it possible to change it?

I have a simulation which doesn't run because of large number of qubits instantiated (from 25 up to 61). The simulation with C# .NET runs perfectly. But when I use a Python host program, the simulation is simply blocked at qubit instantiation.

So I suppose that C# .NET host uses sparse simulator, while Python uses full-state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default simulators chosen either in .NET or in Python, you always specify them explicitly.

In C#, you use different classes for different simulators: `QuantumSimulator` for full state simulator, `SparseSimulator` for sparse simulator.

In Python, you switch the command you use to run Q# operation to use different simulators: `.simulate()` uses full state simulator, and `.simulate_sparse()` uses sparse simulator.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't realize that in Python the method was the key to change simulator. I couldn't find some doc about that.

Comment: This used to be documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/sparse-simulator, but now the documentation switched to Modern QDK, so it talks about the sparse simulator in the Modern QDK. I had to look up the exact syntax in Q# Pocket Guide myself :-)

Comment: (If this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it using the green checkmark - this will prevent the Community bot from bumping it to the top of the list half a year from now)

Comment: Yes, it clearly answer the question. Thanks !
The doc is not completely transfered. And so many things have changed between classic and modern QDK...